# Juce c++ - mouse events don't work

Tags: c++, user-interface, mouseevent, juce

I just started using Juce GUI library for c++. I am trying to create custom listbox where I will display file names later. Now I need to change the background color of the rows of this custom listbox when mouse is in/out/clicked. The problem is that MouseEnter(), MouseExit() and MouseUp() don't work. Here is the code:

```
class LeftExplorerItem : public Component, public MouseListener {

public:

LeftExplorerItem(String name = "LeftExplorerItem") : Component(name), isActive(false) {

    setSize(100, 20);

    addMouseListener(this, true);

}

void paint(Graphics& g) override {

    if (!isActive) g.setColour(Colour(40, 40, 40));
    else g.setColour(Colour(150, 190, 255));
    g.fillRoundedRectangle(2, 2, getWidth() - 4, getHeight() - 4, 4);



    g.setColour(Colours::white);
    g.drawText("Frame #", 40, 0, 100, 25, Justification::centredLeft);



}

void mouseEnter(const MouseEvent& event) override {
    AlertWindow("", "", AlertWindow::AlertIconType::InfoIcon);
    isActive = true;

}

void mouseExit(const MouseEvent& event) override {

    isActive = false;

}

void mouseUp(const MouseEvent& event) override {
    AlertWindow("", "click", AlertWindow::AlertIconType::InfoIcon);
}

void resized() override {

}

private:

bool isActive;

JUCE_DECLARE_NON_COPYABLE_WITH_LEAK_DETECTOR(LeftExplorerItem)
};
```

This is just the class for each item of my custom listbox. Keep in mind that everything appears okay (listbox, all listbox items, etc) the only problem is that mouse events never get triggered. What is missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to derive from `MouseListener` here -- the `Component` class has its own built-in version of all the mouse update methods, all of which have the same signature as those in the `MouseListener` class. Either

a) remove the derivation from `MouseListener` and don't add a mouse listener to the component. Things should just work.

```
class LeftExplorerItem : public Component /*, public MouseListener*/ {

public:

LeftExplorerItem(String name = "LeftExplorerItem") : Component(name), isActive(false) {

    setSize(100, 20);

    // addMouseListener(this, true);

}
```

b) Create a separate class that's derived from `MouseListener` to add the logic you want, and pass  a pointer to an object of that type to the `addMouseListener` method (but this is probably not what you want).

The docs say that the purpose of a MouseListener class is "If you need to get informed about mouse events in a component but can't or don't want to override its methods, you can attach any number of listeners to the component, and these will get told about the events in addition to the component's own callbacks being called." Sounds to me like multiple inheritance is needlessly getting in your way here.

Edit: This version of your class changes color when the mouse enters/exits:

```
class LeftExplorerItem    : public Component
{
public:
    LeftExplorerItem(String name = "LeftExplorerItem") : Component(name), isActive(false) {

        setSize(100, 20);

        //addMouseListener(this, true);

    }

    ~LeftExplorerItem()
    {
    }

    void paint (Graphics& g) override
    {
        if (!isActive) g.setColour(Colour(40, 40, 40));
        else g.setColour(Colour(150, 190, 255));
        g.fillRoundedRectangle(2, 2, getWidth() - 4, getHeight() - 4, 4);



        g.setColour(Colours::white);
        g.drawText("Frame #", 40, 0, 100, 25, Justification::centredLeft);

    }

    void resized() override
    {
        // This method is where you should set the bounds of any child
        // components that your component contains..

    }

    void mouseEnter(const MouseEvent& event) override {
        //AlertWindow("", "", AlertWindow::AlertIconType::InfoIcon);
        isActive = true;
        repaint();

    }

    void mouseExit(const MouseEvent& event) override {

        isActive = false;
        repaint();
    }

    void mouseUp(const MouseEvent& event) override {
        //AlertWindow("", "click", AlertWindow::AlertIconType::InfoIcon);
        repaint();
    }


private:

    bool isActive;
    JUCE_DECLARE_NON_COPYABLE_WITH_LEAK_DETECTOR (LeftExplorerItem)
};
```

Comment: Just tried a) and still events never get triggered. I will try b).

Comment: I copied it into an empty project, and they are getting called, but 1) You're creating AlertWindow objects, but that doesn't display them, so nothing visible happens 2) You don't tell the component to repaint itself, so nothing happens visually there, either.

Comment: Why alertwindow doesn't appear and how to repaint?

Comment: Ohh just remember I need naivemessagebox. Thanks for your answer.